# WordPress REST API validation

Tags: rest-api, validation

I'd like to validate the data sent to my end point.

https://www.shawnhooper.ca/2017/02/15/wp-rest-secrets-found-reading-core-code/
This post referenced the undocumented validation options. I have got 90% of what I need but now need to validate a strings length which I can't seem to figure out.

Basically I need to say the max length is X. I tried 'maxLength' but that isn't working. Has anyone done this or better yet is there any documentation on this, the post I found was quite old.

```
            'args' => array(
                'external_id' => array(
                    'required'      => true,
                    'type'          => 'string',
                    'description'   => 'external id',
                    'maxLength'     => 10
                )
            )
```

Thanks, Andy

Comment: why do you think such validation option exists? You will probably need to write your own validation.

Comment: I thought given the existing validation rules (minimum, maximum, enum) I've been able to use from the link I provided that perhaps maxLength was also an option but as there is no documentation that I could find. Thought it would be more economic than writing my own validation functions. I will try a mixture.

Comment: Yeah minimum and maximum are for numeric parameters, not strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such `maxLength` option in the WP REST API.

You can pass a `validate_callback` though. Example:

```
<?php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
        'args' => array(
            'id' => array(
                'validate_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
                    return is_numeric( $param );
                }
            ),
        ),
    ) );
} );
```

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: I understood this was possible but was trying to use the built in method. I'll try a mixture of the built in and custom.

Comment: In WP 5.5.0 support for maxLength and minLength are added. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.5.1/src/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L1551